# How to normalize Pearson Correlation between 0 and 1?

Tags: normalization, pearson

I came across the formula for the Pearson Correlation but it gives values between -1 and 1. How would I modify the formula so that it gives values between 0 and 1?

Comment: Add 1 and divide by 2 perhaps?

Comment: Thank you Roger! I think that will work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To normalize any set of numbers to be between 0 and 1, subtract the minimum and divide by the range.

In your case the min is -1 and the range is 2, so if a value in your set is -0.5, that value becomes:

```
(-0.5 - (-1)) / 2

= 0.25
```

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you subtract the min and divide by range as opposed to adding 1 and dividing by 2?

Comment: @user3004041 Well the former works in all cases, and the latter works in this specific case.